# Insufficient Privileges: While opening gmail through salesforce -sso

Tags: apex, permissions, single-sign-on, salesforce-id, admin

I have did SSo into my org by following all the steps in the salesforce doc,eventhough when i open gmail from app launcer am getting error as insufficient privileges. how to achieve this...?

Comment: Try giving permission to the App for the profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the below link:

http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/-qyNh0eF-U9vHSaUJZhuNw

and one more thing Check for `Federation ID` in user profile and fill it.

Thanks.